# Can i use nestjs cache service this way?

Tags: redis, nestjs

I need to store temporary tokens for phone/email registration via redis store.
My approach is to create separate cache module with cache service which going to be implement store/retrieve logic.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheMo.registerAsync({
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigType<typeof appConfig>) => ({
        store: redisStore,
        host: configService.REDIS_HOST,
        port: configService.REDIS_PORT,
      }),
      inject: [appConfig.KEY],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    CacheService,
  ],
  exports: [
    CacheService,
  ],
})
export class CacheModule {}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class CacheService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager,
  ) {}

  setTempToken(key) {}

  retrieveTempToken(key) {}
}
```

Then i'm going to import this module in auth module and use **setTempToken**/**retrieveTempToken** methods.

Am i doing this right or there is a better approach?